# SQL select all columns for two distinct columns

Tags: sql, select

The question might be not new but i need help from you .I have sql db table and i want to select all columns for the rows which have distinct values of two columns
.For instance i have a table named **'information' as below**.
What i want is to select all rows with distinct values of **'ctc_card_no'** and **'tarehe'** .Can anyone please help me as i have struggled to get the results

[image]

I need results to be like

[image]

Comment: And what would your output be?

Comment: i want the values of id ,ctc_card_no ,tarehe ,but the values of ctc_card_no and tarehe should not be the same for the results (distinct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ctc_card_no = t.ctc_card_no and t2.tarehe = t.tarehe and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

This returns all *rows* that appear only once in the table, which is how I interpret your question.

EDIT:

If you just want the distinct pairs, you can use `group by`:

```
select min(id), ctc_card_no, tarehe
from t
group by ctc_card_no, tarehe;
```

Comment: okay ,this gives me the results: select min(id), ctc_card_no, tarehe
from t
group by ctc_card_no, tarehe;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select *
from information
where (ctc_card_no, tarehe) in 
  (select ctc_card_no, tarehe
   from information
   group by ctc_card_no, tarehe
   having count(*) = 1
  );
```

Comment: I GET ERROR : Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. WHEN USING YOUR QUERY

Comment: ANY SUGGESTION ,boss

Comment: Huh, no ... not really. I'd say that the above SELECT is correctly written. Could you show (copy/paste) what you exactly did and the way database responded?

Comment: Boss ,look i have edited and shown the results the way i want it to be

Comment: Why is ID = 427 in the result set? It shares CTC_CARD_NO and TAREHE values with ID = 531, so - these aren't distinct. So, either I didn't understand the question, or you didn't explain it well.